# Displaying Cherokee text

Tags: xetex, languages

I have a XeTeX document in Cherokee, but when it compiles to PDF, all of the Cherokee glyphs show up as boxes.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
ᎪᎯ ᎤᎵᏍᏆᎸᏗ ᏕᎨᏌᏗᏒ ᎢᎩᏁᏤᎸ ᎤᏪᏥ ᎤᏮᏔᏅ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎤᏪᎧᏅ ᎤᏤᎵ ᎢᏳᎵᏍᏙᏗᏱ ᏂᎦᏗᏳ ᏧᏓᎴᏅᏛ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎾᏍᏉ ᎬᏗᏍᎬ ᎡᎶᎯ ᏚᏬᏢᏁᎢ;
ᎾᏍᎩ ᏗᎦᎸᏌᏓᏗᏍᎩ ᏥᎨᏒᎩ ᎤᏤᎵ ᎦᎸᏉᏗᏳ ᎨᏒᎢ, ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᎩᏯ ᏗᏟᎶᏍᏔᏅᎯ ᏥᎨᏒᎩ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏄᏍᏛᎢ, ᎠᎴ ᏂᎦᏗᏳ ᏧᏓᎴᏅᏛ ᏥᏚᏍᏆᏂᎪᏗᏕᎬᎩ ᏥᎬᏗᏍᎬᎩ ᎤᎵᏂᎩᏗᏳ ᎧᏁᎬᎢ, ᎾᎯᏳ ᎤᏩᏒ ᎤᏓᏛᏔᏅ ᎤᏅ ᎦᎸᎭ ᎢᎩᏍᎦᏅᏨᎢ, ᎤᏪᏁᎢ ᎠᎦᏘᏏᏗᏢ ᎦᎸᏉᏗᏳ ᎨᏒ ᎦᎸᎳᏗ.
ᎾᏍᎩ ᎢᎦᎢ ᎤᏟ ᎢᏳᏓᎵᏁᎯᏯᏛ ᎾᎬᏁᎴ ᎡᏍᎦ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎤᏘᏯᏍᏓᏁᏗ ᎨᏒ ᎤᏟ ᎢᎦᎸᏉᏗ ᏧᏙᏍᏙᏗ ᏧᏩᏛᏔᏅ.
ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏙᎯᏰᏃ ᎨᏒ ᎦᎪ ᎢᎸᎯᏳ ᎯᎠ ᏄᏪᏎᎶᎢ, ᎠᏇᏥ ᏂᎯ ᎪᎯ ᎢᎦ ᏍᏆᏕᎲᏏ? ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᏉ ᎯᎠ; ᎠᏴ ᏥᎦᏴᎵᎨ ᎨᏎᏍᏗ, ᎾᏍᎩᏃ Ꮎ ᎠᏯᏥ ᎨᏎᏍᏗ?
ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᏉ, ᎾᎯᏳ ᎢᎬᏱ ᎤᏕᏁᎸᎯ ᎡᎶᎯ ᎤᎾᏄᎪᏫᏒ ᎯᎠ ᏄᏪᏎᎢ; ᎠᎴ ᎾᏂᎥ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ ᎤᏁᎳᏅᎯ ᏧᏤᎵ ᏫᎬᏩᏓᏙᎵᏍᏓᏏ.
ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯᏃ ᎯᎠ ᏂᏕᎦᏪᏎᎭ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ ᏧᏤᎵ ᎤᏃᎴ ᏥᏂᏕᎬᏁᎭ, ᎠᎴ ᎠᏥᎸ ᎠᏓᏪᎳᎩᏍᎩ ᏧᏅᏏᏓᏍᏗ ᏥᏂᎬᏁᎭ.
ᎤᏪᏥᏍᎩᏂ ᎯᎠ ᏂᎦᏪᏎᎭ, ᏣᏤᎵ ᎦᏍᎩᎸ, ᏣᏁᎳᏅᎯ, ᏂᎪᎯᎸ ᎠᎴ ᏂᎪᎯᎸ ᏂᎬᏩᏍᏗᏉ; ᎠᏙᎳᏅᏍᏗ ᏚᏳᎪᏛ ᎠᏛᏁᏙᏗ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎠᏙᎳᏅᏍᏗ ᎪᎱᏍᏗ ᏨᏗᎭ ᎾᎿ ᏣᎬᏫᏳᎯ ᎨᏒᎢ.
\end{document}
```

What do I need to do in order to render the Cherokee text correctly?

Comment: If you have the font already installed on your computer, you'll want to set the main font to the name of that font.

Comment: I'm afraid you need a font that have the proper glyphs. Take a look at [this Wikipedia entry](http://chr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode), under *Cherokee-compatible Unicode fonts*; I tried your example with `Aboriginal Serif` and it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a font that has Cherokee glyphs; for instance, FreeSerif has them:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

ᎪᎯ ᎤᎵᏍᏆᎸᏗ ᏕᎨᏌᏗᏒ ᎢᎩᏁᏤᎸ ᎤᏪᏥ ᎤᏮᏔᏅ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎤᏪᎧᏅ ᎤᏤᎵ ᎢᏳᎵᏍᏙᏗᏱ ᏂᎦᏗᏳ ᏧᏓᎴᏅᏛ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎾᏍᏉ ᎬᏗᏍᎬ ᎡᎶᎯ ᏚᏬᏢᏁᎢ; 
ᎾᏍᎩ ᏗᎦᎸᏌᏓᏗᏍᎩ ᏥᎨᏒᎩ ᎤᏤᎵ ᎦᎸᏉᏗᏳ ᎨᏒᎢ, ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᎩᏯ ᏗᏟᎶᏍᏔᏅᎯ ᏥᎨᏒᎩ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏄᏍᏛᎢ, ᎠᎴ ᏂᎦᏗᏳ ᏧᏓᎴᏅᏛ ᏥᏚᏍᏆᏂᎪᏗᏕᎬᎩ 
ᏥᎬᏗᏍᎬᎩ ᎤᎵᏂᎩᏗᏳ ᎧᏁᎬᎢ, ᎾᎯᏳ ᎤᏩᏒ ᎤᏓᏛᏔᏅ ᎤᏅ ᎦᎸᎭ ᎢᎩᏍᎦᏅᏨᎢ, ᎤᏪᏁᎢ ᎠᎦᏘᏏᏗᏢ ᎦᎸᏉᏗᏳ ᎨᏒ ᎦᎸᎳᏗ. ᎾᏍᎩ ᎢᎦᎢ ᎤᏟ 
ᎢᏳᏓᎵᏁᎯᏯᏛ ᎾᎬᏁᎴ ᎡᏍᎦ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎤᏘᏯᏍᏓᏁᏗ ᎨᏒ ᎤᏟ ᎢᎦᎸᏉᏗ ᏧᏙᏍᏙᏗ ᏧᏩᏛᏔᏅ. ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏙᎯᏰᏃ ᎨᏒ ᎦᎪ ᎢᎸᎯᏳ ᎯᎠ 
ᏄᏪᏎᎶᎢ, ᎠᏇᏥ ᏂᎯ ᎪᎯ ᎢᎦ ᏍᏆᏕᎲᏏ? ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᏉ ᎯᎠ; ᎠᏴ ᏥᎦᏴᎵᎨ ᎨᏎᏍᏗ, ᎾᏍᎩᏃ Ꮎ ᎠᏯᏥ ᎨᏎᏍᏗ? ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᏉ, ᎾᎯᏳ ᎢᎬᏱ 
ᎤᏕᏁᎸᎯ ᎡᎶᎯ ᎤᎾᏄᎪᏫᏒ ᎯᎠ ᏄᏪᏎᎢ; ᎠᎴ ᎾᏂᎥ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ ᎤᏁᎳᏅᎯ ᏧᏤᎵ ᏫᎬᏩᏓᏙᎵᏍᏓᏏ. ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯᏃ ᎯᎠ ᏂᏕᎦᏪᏎᎭ, ᎾᏍᎩ 
ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ ᏧᏤᎵ ᎤᏃᎴ ᏥᏂᏕᎬᏁᎭ, ᎠᎴ ᎠᏥᎸ ᎠᏓᏪᎳᎩᏍᎩ ᏧᏅᏏᏓᏍᏗ ᏥᏂᎬᏁᎭ. ᎤᏪᏥᏍᎩᏂ ᎯᎠ ᏂᎦᏪᏎᎭ, ᏣᏤᎵ ᎦᏍᎩᎸ, ᏣᏁᎳᏅᎯ, 
ᏂᎪᎯᎸ ᎠᎴ ᏂᎪᎯᎸ ᏂᎬᏩᏍᏗᏉ; ᎠᏙᎳᏅᏍᏗ ᏚᏳᎪᏛ ᎠᏛᏁᏙᏗ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎠᏙᎳᏅᏍᏗ ᎪᎱᏍᏗ ᏨᏗᎭ ᎾᎿ ᏣᎬᏫᏳᎯ ᎨᏒᎢ.

\end{document}
```

[image]

On my system I have also Plantagenet Cherokee; here is a more complex version; you can use `\cherokeefam` for selecting the Cherokee font (a declaration) or `\textcherokee` for a small insert (command with argument) or even an environment as shown; the `\emergencystretch` command is because the nature of the language makes it difficult to typeset paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cherokeefam}{Plantagenet Cherokee}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcherokee}{\cherokeefam}

\newenvironment{cherokee}
 {\par\cherokeefam\emergencystretch=.5\textwidth}
 {\par}

\begin{document}

Some text in Times

\begin{cherokee}
ᎪᎯ ᎤᎵᏍᏆᎸᏗ ᏕᎨᏌᏗᏒ ᎢᎩᏁᏤᎸ ᎤᏪᏥ ᎤᏮᏔᏅ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎤᏪᎧᏅ ᎤᏤᎵ ᎢᏳᎵᏍᏙᏗᏱ ᏂᎦᏗᏳ ᏧᏓᎴᏅᏛ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎾᏍᏉ 
ᎬᏗᏍᎬ ᎡᎶᎯ ᏚᏬᏢᏁᎢ; ᎾᏍᎩ ᏗᎦᎸᏌᏓᏗᏍᎩ ᏥᎨᏒᎩ ᎤᏤᎵ ᎦᎸᏉᏗᏳ ᎨᏒᎢ, ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᎩᏯ ᏗᏟᎶᏍᏔᏅᎯ ᏥᎨᏒᎩ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏄᏍᏛᎢ, ᎠᎴ ᏂᎦᏗᏳ 
ᏧᏓᎴᏅᏛ ᏥᏚᏍᏆᏂᎪᏗᏕᎬᎩ ᏥᎬᏗᏍᎬᎩ ᎤᎵᏂᎩᏗᏳ ᎧᏁᎬᎢ, ᎾᎯᏳ ᎤᏩᏒ ᎤᏓᏛᏔᏅ ᎤᏅ ᎦᎸᎭ ᎢᎩᏍᎦᏅᏨᎢ, ᎤᏪᏁᎢ ᎠᎦᏘᏏᏗᏢ ᎦᎸᏉᏗᏳ ᎨᏒ 
ᎦᎸᎳᏗ. ᎾᏍᎩ ᎢᎦᎢ ᎤᏟ ᎢᏳᏓᎵᏁᎯᏯᏛ ᎾᎬᏁᎴ ᎡᏍᎦ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎤᏘᏯᏍᏓᏁᏗ ᎨᏒ ᎤᏟ ᎢᎦᎸᏉᏗ ᏧᏙᏍᏙᏗ ᏧᏩᏛᏔᏅ. 
ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏙᎯᏰᏃ ᎨᏒ ᎦᎪ ᎢᎸᎯᏳ ᎯᎠ ᏄᏪᏎᎶᎢ, ᎠᏇᏥ ᏂᎯ ᎪᎯ ᎢᎦ ᏍᏆᏕᎲᏏ? ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᏉ ᎯᎠ; ᎠᏴ ᏥᎦᏴᎵᎨ ᎨᏎᏍᏗ, ᎾᏍᎩᏃ Ꮎ ᎠᏯᏥ 
ᎨᏎᏍᏗ? ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᏉ, ᎾᎯᏳ ᎢᎬᏱ ᎤᏕᏁᎸᎯ ᎡᎶᎯ ᎤᎾᏄᎪᏫᏒ ᎯᎠ ᏄᏪᏎᎢ; ᎠᎴ ᎾᏂᎥ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ ᎤᏁᎳᏅᎯ ᏧᏤᎵ ᏫᎬᏩᏓᏙᎵᏍᏓᏏ. 
ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯᏃ ᎯᎠ ᏂᏕᎦᏪᏎᎭ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᏗᏂᎧᎿᏩᏗᏙᎯ ᏧᏤᎵ ᎤᏃᎴ ᏥᏂᏕᎬᏁᎭ, ᎠᎴ ᎠᏥᎸ ᎠᏓᏪᎳᎩᏍᎩ ᏧᏅᏏᏓᏍᏗ ᏥᏂᎬᏁᎭ. ᎤᏪᏥᏍᎩᏂ ᎯᎠ 
ᏂᎦᏪᏎᎭ, ᏣᏤᎵ ᎦᏍᎩᎸ, ᏣᏁᎳᏅᎯ, ᏂᎪᎯᎸ ᎠᎴ ᏂᎪᎯᎸ ᏂᎬᏩᏍᏗᏉ; ᎠᏙᎳᏅᏍᏗ ᏚᏳᎪᏛ ᎠᏛᏁᏙᏗ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎠᏙᎳᏅᏍᏗ ᎪᎱᏍᏗ ᏨᏗᎭ ᎾᎿ 
ᏣᎬᏫᏳᎯ ᎨᏒᎢ.
\end{cherokee}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Times New Roman doesn't have a the Cherokee glyphs. Select a font that includes the unicode range: 13A0–13FF.

You might try [this page](http://chr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode#Cherokee-compatible_Unicode_fonts) on the Cherokee Wikipedia for a short list of fonts that should work (or try [here](http://chr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode/Cherokee) for the same page in the Sequoyah Syllabary).

For example, changing the font to [`Aboriginal Sans`](http://www.languagegeek.com/font/absans.zip) produces:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Oldie but goodie.  Since this still gets links from duplicate questions, it could use an update for 2021.  This code will auto-detect the script you use and switch to the font and hyphenation patterns for the language you type in.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[import=chr, onchar=ids fonts]{cherokee}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }

%% Aboriginal Serif, Aboriginal Sans and Digohweli, by Christopher Harvey, are
%% available at http://www.languagegeek.com/font/fontdownload.html
%% These fonts do not support the lowercase Cherokee added in Unicode 8.0.
\defaultfontfeatures[AboriginalSerif]{
  Renderer = HarfBuzz,
  Ligatures=Common,
  UprightFont = *REGULAR ,
  BoldFont = *BOLD ,
  ItalicFont = *ITALIC ,
  BoldItalicFont = *BOLDITALIC ,
  Extension = .ttf }
\defaultfontfeatures[AboriginalSans]{
  Renderer = HarfBuzz,
  Ligatures= {Common, Discretionary},
  UprightFont = *REGULAR ,
  BoldFont = *BOLD ,
  ItalicFont = *ITALIC ,
  BoldItalicFont = *BOLDITALIC ,
  Extension = .ttf }
%% An alternative is Noto Sans Cherokee, availabe at
%% https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-cher
%% This font comes in numerous weights, so select the pair that matches your
%% other fonts, e.g. Medium and ExtraBold or Light and Semibold. It has no
%% italics.
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSansCherokee]{
  Renderer = HarfBuzz,
  UprightFont=*-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  Extension = .ttf
}
%% Everson Mono is available at: https://www.evertype.com/emono/

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\babelfont[cherokee]{rm}
          {AboriginalSerif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Carlito}
\babelfont[cherokee]{sf}
          {NotoSansCherokee}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Everson Mono}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
\section*{The Universal Declaration of Human Rights in ᏣᎳᎩ ᎦᏬᏂᎯᏍᏗ}

\subsection*{Preamble/ᎬᏂᏳᏉ ᎧᏃᎮᏛ}

\sffamily
Ꭼꮒᏻꮙ ꮧꮣꮒꮈꮸ ꮎꮝꭹ ꭰꮰꮿꮝꮧꮝꭹ ꭰꮲꮙꮩꮧ ꭰꮄ ꮎꮝꭹꮓ ꭲꭶꮨ ꭰꮄ ꭴꮩꭿᏻꭿꮿ ꭴꮒꮂ ꭲᏻꮎꮫꮧ ꮎꮝꭹꮓ ꮒꭶꮣ ꭰꮒꮃ ꮎꮝꭹ ꭰꮒᏼꮻ ꮟꮣꮑꮈ ꭰꮎꮑꮈ ꮎꮎꭲ ꮧꭶꭻꮝꮣꭲ ꮩꭿ ꭰꮥꮧꭲ, ꮪᏻꭺꮫ ꭴꮝꮣᏺꭿꮝꮧ ꭰꮄ ꮕꮹꮩꭿꮿꮫ ꮎꮏ ꮎꮝꭹ ꭱꮆꭿ,

Ꭼꭼꮒᏻꮙ ꭰꭶꮞꮝꮤꮕꮎ ꭰꮄ ꮒꭶꮈꮙꮫꮎ ꮎꮝꭹꮎ ꭰꮒᏼꮻ ꭴꮒꮂ ꭲᏻꮎꮫꮧꭲ

Ꭴꮒꮂꭲ ꮻꮒꮪꮅꮝꮤꮕꭹ ꮎ ꭴꮒꮝꭶꮞꮨ ꮎꮎꮫꮑꮕ ꮎꮝꭹꮎꮓ ꭴꮒꮂ ꭶꮆꮢꮝꮤꮕ ꭰꮤꮃꮼꭿꮝꮧ ꮎꮝꭹ ꮷꮔꭺꮩꮧᏹ ꭴꮎꮥꮧᏹ ᏼꮻ, ꭰꮄ ꮎꮝꭹ ꭱꮆꭿ ꭴꮇꮴ ꮎꮏꭲ ꮎꮝꭹꮎꮓ ꭰꮒᏼꮻ ꭰꮞ ꭰꮅꭾꮅꮝꮧ ꮩꭿ ꭶꮼꮒꭿꮝꮧ ꭰꮄ ꭴꮓꭿᏻꮢ ꭰꮄ ꮩꭿ ꭰꮥꮧꭲ ꮎꮝꭹꮎ ꮒꭶꮎᏸꭿꮝꮫꮎ ꭰꮄ ꭷꮑꮸꭹ ꭴꮎꮪꮈꮣ ꮕꮅꮝꮤꮕꭹ ꮎꮝꭹ ꮹꭶꮈꮃꮧᏼ ꭰꮎꮪꮈꮤꮕ ꮎꮝꭹ ꮎꮒꭶꭵꮚ ᏼꮻ,
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sans Cherokee sample]

That example requires LuaLaTeX. If you try to set XeLaTeX up to auto-detect Cherokee, using `ucharclasses`, a few characters from Unicode 13.0, such as Ᏻ, will not be properly auto-detected, and you will need to either avoid them or use explicit language tags, such as `\begin{cherokee}`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\babelprovide[import=chr]{cherokee}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }

%% Aboriginal Serif, Aboriginal Sans and Digohweli, by Christopher Harvey, are
%% available at http://www.languagegeek.com/font/fontdownload.html
%% These fonts do not support the lowercase Cherokee added in Unicode 8.0.
\defaultfontfeatures[AboriginalSerif]{
  Ligatures=Common,
  UprightFont = *REGULAR ,
  BoldFont = *BOLD ,
  ItalicFont = *ITALIC ,
  BoldItalicFont = *BOLDITALIC ,
  Extension = .ttf }
\defaultfontfeatures[AboriginalSans]{
  Ligatures= {Common, Discretionary},
  UprightFont = *REGULAR ,
  BoldFont = *BOLD ,
  ItalicFont = *ITALIC ,
  BoldItalicFont = *BOLDITALIC ,
  Extension = .ttf }
%% An alternative is Noto Sans Cherokee, availabe at
%% https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-cher
%% This font comes in numerous weights, so select the pair that matches your
%% other fonts, e.g. Medium and ExtraBold or Light and Semibold. It has no
%% italics.
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSansCherokee]{
  UprightFont=*-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  Extension = .ttf
}
%% Everson Mono is available at: https://www.evertype.com/emono/

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\babelfont[cherokee]{rm}
          {AboriginalSerif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Carlito}
\babelfont[cherokee]{sf}
          {AboriginalSans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Everson Mono}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{english}}{}
\setTransitionsForCherokeeFull{\selectlanguage{cherokee}}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}
\section*{The Universal Declaration of Human Rights in ᏣᎳᎩ ᎦᏬᏂᎯᏍᏗ}

\subsection*{Preamble/ᎬᏂᏳᏉ ᎧᏃᎮᏛ}

\sffamily
ᎬᏂᏳᏉ ᏗᏓᏂᎸᏨ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎠᏠᏯᏍᏗᏍᎩ ᎠᏢᏉᏙᏗ ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᎩᏃ ᎢᎦᏘ ᎠᎴ ᎤᏙᎯᏳᎯᏯ ᎤᏂᎲ ᎢᏳᎾᏛᏗ ᎾᏍᎩᏃ ᏂᎦᏓ ᎠᏂᎳ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎠᏂᏴᏫ ᏏᏓᏁᎸ ᎠᎾᏁᎸ ᎾᎾᎢ ᏗᎦᎫᏍᏓᎢ ᏙᎯ ᎠᏕᏗᎢ, ᏚᏳᎪᏛ ᎤᏍᏓᏲᎯᏍᏗ ᎠᎴ ᏅᏩᏙᎯᏯᏛ ᎾᎿ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎡᎶᎯ,

ᎬᏂᏳᏉ ᎠᎦᏎᏍᏔᏅᎾ ᎠᎴ ᏂᎦᎸᏉᏛᎾ ᎾᏍᎩᎾ ᎠᏂᏴᏫ ᎤᏂᎲ ᎢᏳᎾᏛᏗᎢ ᎤᏂᎲᎢ ᏫᏂᏚᎵᏍᏔᏅᎩ Ꮎ ᎤᏂᏍᎦᏎᏘ ᎾᎾᏛᏁᏅ ᎾᏍᎩᎾᏃ ᎤᏂᎲ ᎦᎶᏒᏍᏔᏅ ᎠᏔᎳᏬᎯᏍᏗ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏧᏄᎪᏙᏗᏱ ᎤᎾᏕᏗᏱ ᏴᏫ, ᎠᎴ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎡᎶᎯ ᎤᎷᏤ ᎾᎿᎢ ᎾᏍᎩᎾᏃ ᎠᏂᏴᏫ ᎠᏎ ᎠᎵᎮᎵᏍᏗ ᏙᎯ ᎦᏬᏂᎯᏍᏗ ᎠᎴ ᎤᏃᎯᏳᏒ ᎠᎴ ᏙᎯ ᎠᏕᏗᎢ ᎾᏍᎩᎾ ᏂᎦᎾᏰᎯᏍᏛᎾ ᎠᎴ ᎧᏁᏨᎩ ᎤᎾᏚᎸᏓ ᏅᎵᏍᏔᏅᎩ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏩᎦᎸᎳᏗᏴ ᎠᎾᏚᎸᏔᏅ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎾᏂᎦᎥᏊ ᏴᏫ,

ᎬᏂᏳᏉ ᎾᎢ ᎤᎵᏍᎨᏛ, ᎾᏍᎩᎾ ᎠᏍᎦᏯ ᎬᏍᏗᏰᏙᏗ ᏂᎨᏒᎾ ᏱᎩ ᎾᏍᎩ ᎪᎱᏍᏗ ᏄᏓᏁᏢᎾ, ᎣᏂ ᎤᏓᎷᎸ ᎤᏓᏁᏟᏴᏓ, ᏳᏓᏱᎸ ᎤᏬᎯᏳᏗ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏧᎦᏘᎸᏍᏗ ᏂᏓᏤᏢᎾᏉ ᎾᎾᏛᏁᎲᎩ ᎠᎴ ᎤᏲ ᎢᏯᏓᏛᏁᎯ, ᎾᏍᎩ ᎠᏂᏴᏫ ᎤᏂᎲ ᏳᎾᏛᏁᏗᎢ ᎡᎵᏍᏗ ᎠᎵᏏᏅᏙᏗ ᏱᎩ ᎾᎥᎢ ᎾᏍᎩ ᏧᏂᎧᎾᏩᏛᏍᏙᏗ ᏗᎧᎿᏩᏛᏍᏗ,
\end{document}
```

If you only need a few words in Cherokee, and you must use PDFTeX, one solution is to compile the individual word as a standalone PDF with LuaTeX, then include that PDF in your main document as a graphic. This will embed the Unicode font you used, and give you searchable, copyable text.

For example, first compile this to Tsalagi.pdf in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

%% Digohweli is available at
%% http://www.languagegeek.com/font/fontdownload.html
\newfontface\cherokeefont{Digohweli}[
  Ligatures=Common,
  Script=Cherokee,
  Language=Cherokee ]

\begin{document}
\cherokeefont ᎬᏂᏳᏉ ᎧᏃᎮᏛ
\end{document}
```

You can then include Tsalagi.pdf in your PDFTeX document. This code will embed your Cherokee word and scale it to the height of the current font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\capheight}
\newcommand\Tsalagi{%
  \settoheight{\capheight}{H}%
  \includegraphics[height=\capheight]{Tsalagi.pdf}}

\begin{document}
Text in English and {\Tsalagi}.

{\large Big text in English and {\Tsalagi}.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Digohweli sample]

(These fonts are not a great match for each other, admittedly, but the font choices here are just examples.)